# Can't click on a navbar dropdown menu option with a custom media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

After sucessfully using the answer posted here [navbar dropdown menus display issue on mobile and small devices with media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780994/navbar-dropdown-menus-display-issue-on-mobile-and-small-devices-with-media-query), I have now this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qxgy6L9b/23/.

However, I still have an issue I can't accomplish to fix. If i click on the second dropdown list, it is not possible to click on any item of this submenu. It is due to the fact there is another list item just after. If i remove this item list, the dropdown menu items are clickable.

I guess, this is linked to this CSS code:

```
   .dropdown-menu{
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: inherit;
  }
```

I tried several things but impossible to make the items of the second dropdown list clickable if I have an additional item just after.

Does anybody have an idea ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have jquery included properly?

Comment: I think JQuery is included correctly since it work for a viewport < 768px. It seems to be more linked to my custom CSS media query which is not correclty built.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're trying to do? For instance, you're trying click which link and then which link. It's difficult to follow where you're getting hung up.

Comment: @Gray, yes of course : Actually, if you consider the fiddle I posted, if you click on the first dropdown list, you can actually hover any item of this dropdown list and click on it. But, if you use the second dropdown list, you can see that you can't hover or click on any item. If you do that, it's the "Clickable Link" option which is selected and used.What I would want is that the second dropdown menu works as the first one.

Comment: @ptitoliv, I wonder if this issue isn't specific to a browser. It seems like it's working okay to me. If I click the 'hamburger' icon, the main dropdown menu appears. I can hover over and click any link. The color of the text changes upon hover. If I click either of the two links that read 'Dropdown', both result in a nested dropdown menu containing links to 'Action', 'Another action', 'Something else here', and one or more 'Separated link's. I can hover over or click any of those and get the same behavior. The text color changes. If I click one of those nested links, the menu collapses.

Comment: Here, I can reproduce on all browsers I have (Firefox, Seamonkey and Chrome). But the bug is only when my media query is enabled which that means when the viewport size is beteween 768px and 991. If you're under this size, the collapse style is the small screen one and my media query is not enabled.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a z-index issue?

Comment: I don't know actually how to adjust z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. I replaced the position from absolute to relative and now I have the correct behaviour.

Hope it will help others people :)